# Why does IIS accept requests before RoleEntryPoint.OnStart returns?

Tags: windows, iis, azure, cloud, azure-web-roles

I'm playing with Azure sample [from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg433178) on Compute Emulator and I found that if I make `OnStart()` in my class inherited from `RoleEntryPoint` rather slow to return the .aspx page in the web role accepts HTTP requests even before `OnStart()` returns.

I find it rather confusing - why would IIS accept requests to the role that hasn't yet started?

Comment: Hum, in my experience Compute Emulator is a rather loose replicate of the Azure in-cloud behavior. So this quirk does mean that you will experience the same on the cloud.

Comment: Actually I experience the same issue (i.e. the role accepting instances while still being busy) when deployed too: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/885c0b7b-c19e-4969-99c8-9186e53f16c3/azure-cloud-service-internal-server-error-500-while-scaling-up?forum=windowsazuretroubleshooting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The emulator does not emulate the load balancer 100%.  For the cloud, when your role is in OnStart() you are reported to the LB as Busy and no traffic will be routed to it.  Once you return from OnStart() with true, it will take a few seconds or so but only then will the LB start to route to it.  You can test this yourself by tracing in your OnStart() and putting a big Sleep() in there.  You won't be able to reach your instance (over non lingering ports).

You can of course ask the LB to ignore the Ready status and it will route even when busy - that is done by specifying ignoreRoleInstanceStatus="true" on the endpoint.

Comment: Are there any other implications for having `ignoreRoleInstanceStatus=true` ??

Comment: If you did that on port 80, it would mean that users will hit your web instances before they are ready and they will be served errors from IIS (503 or whatever).  It makes more sense for ports that are not necessarily tied to role status (e.g. RDP 3389).