# How are HTTP requests dispatched to an Azure web role instance while the instance is restarting due to an exception?

Tags: iis, azure, cloud

I'm reviewing my Azure web role logs and see the following. At some moment in the past the thread that was having `RoleEntryPoint.Run()` invoked on it threw an exception that was propagated to the caller of `Run()` and the Azure runtime tried to restart the instance by calling `RoleEntryPoint.OnStart()`. Now my `OnStart()` implementation takes several minutes to complete and I see that HTTP requests were being dispatched to IIS while `OnStart()` was in progress.

Is that the expected behavior? Shouldn't the Azure infrastructure wait till the instance `OnStart()` completes successfully? How do I make Azure exclude the role from dispatching HTTP requests onto it until `OnStart()` completes successfully?

Answer (score 0):

The state  of your instance will only change to Ready (and accept requests from the LB) if the  OnStart method returns true. Before that its status will be Busy (and not accept requests from the LB) as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleentrypoint.onstart.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh127476.aspx).

There are a few cases where this doesn't apply:

- You used the [ignoreRoleInstanceStatus](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/02/23/what-is-ignoreroleinstancestatus-setting-in-windows-azure.aspx) attribute in the service definition.
- You are running in the emulator ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355988/why-does-iis-accept-requests-before-roleentrypoint-onstart-returns))

Or could it be that the request comes from processes running locally on your instance? Or from another instance?

Comment: Interesting. The code is running on a live cloud without `ignoreRoleInstanceStatus` set and requests are definitely from the outside world.